# Передача переменных из PHP в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы "сайт" работал не со своими данными, а обращался к базе за ними.
Подключил вроде все нормально...
пишу запрос

```
 <?php
     $connect_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=MD user=postgres      password=1";
    $conn = pg_pconnect($connect_string);
    $result = pg_query($conn, 'select region_name from "Region" where   region_id=1');
    $arraks = pg_fetch_array ($result);
    $karsk = $arraks[0];
pg_close( $conn); ?>
```

после этого в js принимаю значение

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


var perst = '<?php echo $karsk;?>';....
```

и все работает, передал это значение в другую, вывел на карту, ну... все хорошо.
решил по такому же принципу сделать и передать вторую переменную
... код один в один, кроме имен karsk ,arraks, perst .... в php части все отлично, к базе обратился, значение получил, вывел, проверил, все хорошо, перехожу к js.... пишу код, и ничего, работа странички прекратилась, карта не отображается... просто пятно......
что, как сделать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Посмотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: если я правильно понял где смотреть....Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: это может быть из-за пробела в имени в бд? или что-то такое?

Comment: судя по ошибке - где-то забыли кавычку или ; . Пользуйтесь сокращенной формой, удобнее `<?=$karsk?>`

Comment: спасибо большое вам, нашел ошибку... не корректные данные были